# is there any way to exclude xxxhdpi resources when building an apk

Tags: android, gradle, apk

My problem is that the resources in xxxhdpi folder is taking up a lot of storage，making the final apk unnecessarily large

This is especially true when building the debug apk

For different abis we can use abifilters，is there anything like that for resources？

Splits apk is not what i want since it builds one apk for each density folder

Comment: What about simply not providing them in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tested it but you can perhaps use the `android.splits.density` block to exclude screen densities

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#configure-separate-apks-per-screen-density

Extract:

```
android {
  ...
  splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
    density {

      // Enables building multiple APKs.
      enable true

      // Specifies a list of screen densities Gradle should not create APKs for.
      exclude "xxxhdpi"
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will produce multiple apks for each density that is not excluded, unfortunately that is not what I wanted